# Identify Microsoft Band using some unique identifier

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, microsoft-band

I'm developing on UWP for band. Is there any way to identify a connected band on some serial number/ unique ID or something else. Like i found the connected bands as

```
IBandInfo[] pairedBands = await BandClientManager.Instance.GetBandsAsync();
```

If there is not any way then if I can inherit some method with Bluetooth API and identify on the basis of Bluetooth ID. Need help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every Microsoft Band have unique "Serial ID". You can check it in **"Setting Tile" > "Device Info"**.

But there is no method in Microsoft Band SDK to get that number.

For now, the only way to identify Band is **Band Name**

```
using Microsoft.Band;

IBandInfo[] pairedBands = await
BandClientManager.Instance.GetBandsAsync();
```

Using BandClientManager you can get to **Band Name**.

Comment: How the hell band can be identified if two bands have same name?

Comment: when band disconnects and reconnect then what will be UUID ? :D